# Woocommerce Styling Quantity Input (OceanWP)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I increase the size and change the color of the Quantity Input in the product page?
I use the OceanWP theme.

In the CSS option of the Theme I added this:

```
.woocommerce .quantity input {
width: 100%;
}
```

And it actually increased the quantity field a little bit, but I would like it to span the entire width of the page just like the Add To Cart button.

[Here is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAL9A.png)

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/MfCA5V

Comment: yes! it would be great